# Python does not start the for loop with another index

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

This is the code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    i=4
    for i in range(n):
        print(i)
```

I want it to print from 4 to n values, but it always starts printing from 0.

In C++, the value for i would start from 4 but in Python3, it always starts from 0.

Comment: use `range(4, n+1)`

Comment: "In C++, the value for i would start from 4 but in Python3, it always starts from 0." You're assuming you're doing it correctly. `for(int i = j; i < k; i += l)` is equivalent to `for i in range(j, k, l)`. (minus the ability to change `i` mid iterations)

Comment: Actually easiest would be:`print('\n'.join([i for i in range(4,int(input())+1)]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loop is little different in python

In python, at each iteration of the loop, the variable `i` is chosen as the next element in `range(4)`.

But, in C, C++, the variable `i` have managed by both the loop increment

replace

```
 for i in range(n):
```

with

```
for i in range(4, n+1):
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `for` loops don't work the way they do in, say, Java or C. The iteration variable `i` is assigned to each element of `range(n)` (which is array-like) at the beginning of each iteration of the loop. So when you assign `i = 4`, the value is overwritten to the first value of `range(n)`, which is `0`.

You can loop from `4` to `n`:

```
for i in range(4, n + 1):
    print(i)
```

note that `range` is inclusive for the start and exclusive for the end.

Comment: To print "from 4 to n" values as OP described, you would need `range(4, n + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

`range(start,end)` will assign `start` to `i` up to `end`:

```
for i in range(4, n+1):
    print(i)
```